# Alternatives to (or suggestion on how to make work) angular2-grid in Angular 6

Tags: angular, migration, angular6

I am migrating an Angular4 app to the latest version of Angular6. Since Angular2, we have been using angular2-grid to offer a grid-based system on which one can place widgets and set their sizes and positions. However, in Angular 6, angular2-grid does not seem to work - it does not honor the positions of existing widgets, resizing makes the widgets small and unable to expand, and generally does not work as expected.

[image: Expected Behaviour]

This is how the widgets are supposed to be organized on the grid (each black box is a widget, hiding content for confidentiality)

[image: Observed Behaviour]

This is the observed behaviour. Notice how the widgets are overlapping.

I am looking for either suggestions on making this library work on Angular 6, or some good library that I can replace with ease and minimal work.

Comment: Could you please insert your code in the question? Please provide a [_Minimal, Complete and Verifiable_ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can track down the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but the code is under NDA and I cannot reveal any part of it. It is a div in html with the ngGrid property set, as per angular2-grid documentations. I'm just wondering if someone else had faced similar issues and how they fixed it, either by swapping the library or by setting some params.